# Sharepoint 2013, get data from list to ClientPeoplePicker

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sh

In Sharepoint 2013,
I tried to get user information from custom list to display in Edit form, that will show in control ClientPeoplePicker.

I searched around and try with 2 solutions:

```
private void LoadUserToPeoplePicker(SPListItem item, string colName, ClientPeoplePicker peoplePicker)
    {
        //Get user information from list
        var user = item[colName] as string;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
        {
            var spUser = new SPFieldUserValue(SPContext.Current.Web, user);

            //Solution 01
            var entity = new PickerEntity();
            entity.Key = spUser.LookupValue;

            PeopleEditor editor = new PeopleEditor();
            entity = editor.ValidateEntity(entity);

            peoplePicker.AddEntities(new List<PickerEntity> { entity });

            //Solution 02
            //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(spUser.User.Email))
            //{
            //    peoplePicker.InitialUserAccounts = spUser.User.Email;
            //}
        }
    }
```

I call them in override of Nintex form:  protected override void OnFormControlDataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)

Here is error I got:

> Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser' in Assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' is not marked as serializable.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser' in Assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' is not marked as serializable.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SerializationException: Type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser' in Assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' is not marked as serializable.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type) +14210117
   System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context) +408
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo() +420
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +532
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.Serialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder) +270
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck) +814
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck) +322
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph) +17
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value) +3526

[ArgumentException: Error serializing value 'i:0#.w|fsoft.fpt.vn\hoavt2' of type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.SPUser.']
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.SerializeValue(SerializerBinaryWriter writer, Object value) +4068
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Serialize(Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +103
   System.Web.UI.Util.SerializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter2 formatter, Object stateGraph, Purpose purpose) +67
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Save() +173
   System.Web.UI.Page.SaveAllState() +1161
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4660

Anybody is facing with that issue, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was wrong :)
It's not in that function, it on the other

```
private void ExtractValueForApprover(IOrderedDictionary dictionary, ClientPeoplePicker peoplePicker,
        string colName)
    {
        if (peoplePicker == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(colName))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (peoplePicker.ResolvedEntities.Count > 0)
        {
            var user = SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(peoplePicker.GetPickerEntity().Key);

            AddValueToDictionary(colName, user.LoginName, dictionary);
        }
    }
```

I was extracted this line: SPContext.Current.Web.EnsureUser(peoplePicker.GetPickerEntity().Key) to extension method, then above error happening.

It might be helpful for you guys.

Thanks!